# RequireJS module attempts to load shim'ed module

Tags: requirejs, shim

I'm having an issue attempting to create a RequireJS shim for some javascript code that was written by another team in my organization.  The script is loaded via a noraml HTML script as such:

```
<script src="MyCustomModule.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My main.js contains the following:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: { 'text': 'durandal/amd/text' },
    shim: {
        'MyCustomModule': { exports: 'My.Custom.Module' }
    }
});
```

And I have tried accessing the custom module in a variety of ways, but this is my current code:

```
define(['MyCustomModule'], function (require, MyCustomModule) {
 ...
}
```

But each time the page/app loads I get an error from RequireJS indicating that it failed to load `app/MyCustomModule.js` (and I can see the 404 error in the console where it attempted to request the file from the server).  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to include `MyCustomModule` in `paths`:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': 'durandal/amd/text'
        'MyCustomModule': 'path/to/MyCustomModule'
    },
    shim: {
        'MyCustomModule': {
            exports: 'My.Custom.Module'
        }
    }
});
```

If you don't do that, `define(['MyCustomModule'] (...)` will look for the dependency in the `baseUrl` location, in your case: `app/MyCustomModule`.

---

In other words: `shim` can't "pick up" global variables that are not loaded by RequireJS.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere, the documentation at: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim doesn't mention anything about setting up the paths (but I will definitely try it when I get back to work tomorrow).

Comment: Pretty much entire chapter you linked *kind of* implies shim only works for dependencies loaded by RequireJS ( *"assumes [libraries] have been installed in the baseUrl directory. If not, then you may need to set a paths config for them:"*, *"To load modules that are part of or use shim config, a normal require/define call is needed"*, etc.), but you're right, it doesn't seem to mention it explicitly. Here's an alternative (shim-less) solution to an identical problem suggested by James Burke himself: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/requirejs/CI79vnKEsWM/2Vmi38yWC_cJ

Comment: This is essentially what we already do, I was hoping to clean up about 15 of these files by implementing shims.  Seems like the shims are a "cleaner" way of doing this.  Maybe not...

Comment: This did indeed fix it, but caused other problems.  Looks like we should stick with the solution suggested by James Burke.  Thanks for the info.